# Dealing with hashes inside arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash, iteration

Is there a better way to do this?
I have two arrays of hashes, and I want to get an array of hashes where the days overlap, with the versions set to the intersection (ie. version1_for_arr1 && version1_for_arr2).

arr1 is

```
[{:day=>day1, :version1=>true, :version2=>false, :version3=>true},
 {:day=>day3, :version1=>false, :version2=>false, :version3=>true},
 {:day=>day4, :version1=>true, :version2=>false, :version3=>false},
 {:day=>day5, :version1=>true, :version2=>true, :version3=>true},
 {:day=>day10, :version1=>true, :version2=>true, :version3=>true},
 {:day=>day15, :version1=>true, :version2=>false, :version3=>false}]
```

arr2 is

```
[{:day=>day1, :version1=>false, :version2=>false, :version3=>true},
 {:day=>day2, :version1=>false, :version2=>false, :version3=>true},
 {:day=>day4, :version1=>true, :version2=>true, :version3=>false},
 {:day=>day5, :version1=>false, :version2=>true, :version3=>true},
 {:day=>day15, :version1=>true, :version2=>false, :version3=>false}]
```

In this case the final array would be:

```
[{:day=>day1, :version1=>false, :version2=>false, :version3=>true},
 {:day=>day4, :version1=>true, :version2=>false, :version3=>false},
 {:day=>day5, :version1=>false, :version2=>true, :version3=>true},
 {:day=>day15, :version1=>true, :version2=>false, :version3=>false}]
```

The only way I can think to do this is as nested iterations, ie

```
days=[]
arr1.each do |d1|
  arr2.each do |d2|
    if d1[:day]==d2[:day]
      days<<Hash.new(:day=>d1, :version1=>(d1[:version1]&&d2[:version1], :version2=>(d1[:version2]&&d2[:version2], :version3=>(d1[:version3]&&d2[:version3])
    end
  end
end
```

However, that seems like it is tremendously expensive when it gets scaled and the arrays get very large. It's iterating n^n times.

I did see this, http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Loop_over_multiple_arrays_simultaneously#Ruby on rassoc and assoc, but it looks like they need to be arrays inside of arrays, and I later use the resulting hashes as hashes.

Is there a better way to do this? I keep coming up with other ideas but when I really examine them, they all come back to two nested iterations.

Comment: Can you explain what this data is? Each hash and each array have noticeable patterns, meaning you can (and probably should) convert them into classes.

Comment: Each array represents the occurrences of a search term (we let people search for up to two terms), and each hash is the day object  one occurrence of that search term belongs to and may or may not be included in each of several versions (standard, and/or several other options), represented by the version booleans. I don't see how it would work to have them as classes (or where in rails they would go.) This is just a small section of the search algorithm. I'm trying to get the days and versions for each day where the two search terms intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting these two arrays of hashes from?  If you're storing search terms in a SQL database, this seems like something you could do using a query.

Otherwise, you might look into using a Set to find the intersection of the dates.

```
require 'set'

def daylist(arr)
  arr.map { |a| a[:day] }
end

set1 = Set.new(daylist(arr1))
set2 = Set.new(daylist(arr2))

days = set1.intersection(set2)

result = ....
```

I'm stopping there because as I'm looking at your data further, I'm wondering if you can restructure it.  I feel like it might make it easier to transform if instead of an array of hashes, you make a hash of arrays:

```
require 'set'

h1 = {
  day1: [ true, false, true ],
  day3: [ false, false, true ],
  day4: [ true, false, false ],
  day5: [ true, true, true ],
  day10: [ true, true, true ],
  day15: [ true, false, false ]
}

h2 = {
  day1: [ false, false, true ],
  day2: [ false, false, true ],
  day4: [ true, true, false ],
  day5: [ false, true, true ],
  day15: [ true, false, false ]
}

# Intersect them.
set1 = Set.new(h1.keys)
set2 = Set.new(h2.keys)
intersection = set1.intersection(set2)

# Compute the lval & rval arrays
anded = intersection.map do |day|
  h1[day].each_with_index.map { |x, i| x && h2[day][i] }
end

# Convert them back into a Hash like our originals
final = Hash[intersection.zip(anded)]
```

Of course, if this stuff is coming out of Postgres or something then you're way better off trying to do this in a query.  In that case everything I just wrote will be useless to you. ;)

Comment: The restructuring of the data worked well. I didn't realize you could use the days themselves as the hash keys.